# Enable Form when stores loaded in ExtJs

Tags: forms, extjs, store

How to enable form panel only when stores are loaded in ExtJs? 
I have tried this but is not working :

```
function enableForm(allStores, form) {
    var loadedStores = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < allStores.length; ++i) {
        allStores[i].on('load', function () {
        if (++loadedStores === allStores.length) {
            form.enable();
        }
        },
    null, {single: true});
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Loading the stores later works with `autoLoad : false`.

Comment: That looks reasonable. What do you mean it's "not working"? What debugging have you done?

Comment: That may fail if some of your stores are already loaded when you run this code. Does your code guarantee this can't happen?

Comment: @rixo Thanks, the question is updated with the solution.